# How to use grafana-cli on docker installed Grafana?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, grafana

I have installed [grafana via docker](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/).

Is it possible to export and run [grafana-cli](http://docs.grafana.org/administration/cli/) on my host?

Comment: You need `grafana-cli` to be used as a command on host so you don't need get inside container everytime? Or you want to it to collect data from host and work on that?

Answer (score 16):

If you meant running Grafana with some plugins installed, you can do it by passing a list of plugin names to a variable called **GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS**.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=gridprotectionalliance-openhistorian-datasource,gridprotectionalliance-osisoftpi-datasource" grafana/grafana
```

I did this on Grafana 4.x

[Installing plugins for Grafana 3 "or above"](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker#installing-plugins-for-grafana-3)

Answer (score 14):

For a full automatic setup of your Grafana install with the plugins you want I would follow [Ricardo's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849395/3720). Its much better if you can configure your entire container as wanted in a single hit like that.

However if you are just playing with the plugins and want to install some manually, then you can access a shell on the running docker instance from the host.

`host:~$ docker exec -it grafana /bin/bash`

... assuming you named the docker container "grafana" otherwise you will need to substitute the given container name. The shell prompt that returns will allow you to run the standard

`root@3e04b4578ebe:/# grafana-cli plugins install ....`

Be warned that it may tell you to run `service grafana-server restart` afterwards. In my experience that didn't work (Not sure it runs as a traditional service in the container). However if you exit the container, and restart the container from the host...

`host:~$ docker restart grafana`

That should restart the grafana service and your new plugins should be in place.

Answer (score 5):

**Grafana running in docker container**

> Docker installed on Windows 10

**Test: command to display grafana-cli help**

```
c:\>docker exec -it grafana grafana-cli --help
```

Tested with a version: Version 6.4.4 November 6, 2019